# Scala initialize collection from Java iterable

Tags: scala

In scala, how can I initialize a scala collection from a Java iterable, in a clean idiomatic way?

Here's somewhat lame code taking a less functional approach for that:

```
var collection = Seq[MyClass]() 

while (iterator.hasNext) { 
  val asArray: Array[String] = iterator.next.toArray
  val val2 = asArray(2)
  val val3 = asArray(3)
  collection = collection :+ new MyClass(val2, val3)
}
```

How can initialization of a collection from a Java iterable take place more idiomatically?

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val collection = iterator.asScala.map{ x =>
  val asArray = x.toArray
  new MyClass(asArray(2), asArray(3))
}.toIndexedSeq
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala can convert to and from Java collections seamlessly, provided you have imported the conversion helpers like below:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val jl = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
jl.add("Hello")
jl.add("There")

val collection = j1.map{ x => new MyClass(x(2), x(3)) }.toList
```